# got error when building expression: buildTree error: unset parameter: ConditionBuilder

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I have dynamodb client written in go, i want to add new condition builder parameter to support two parameters and with given parameters i want to execute between operator but getting this error:

```
got error when building expression: buildTree error: unset parameter: ConditionBuilder
```

this is my implementation:

```
func (dbClient Client) query(ctx context.Context, keyCondition, filterCondition, dateRangeCondition db.Condition, items interface{}, indexName *string, consistentRead *bool) error {
    var keyCondBuilder expression.KeyConditionBuilder
    keyCondition.ForEach(func(key string, value interface{}) {
        if keyCondBuilder.IsSet() {
            keyCondBuilder = keyCondBuilder.And(expression.Key(key).Equal(expression.Value(value)))
        } else {
            keyCondBuilder = expression.Key(key).Equal(expression.Value(value))
        }
    })

    builder := expression.NewBuilder().WithKeyCondition(keyCondBuilder)

    var filterCondBuilder expression.ConditionBuilder
    if filterCondition != nil {
        filterCondition.ForEach(func(key string, value interface{}) {
            if filterCondBuilder.IsSet() {
                filterCondBuilder = filterCondBuilder.And(expression.Name(key).Equal(expression.Value(value)))
            } else {
                filterCondBuilder = expression.Name(key).Equal(expression.Value(value))
            }
        })
        builder = builder.WithFilter(filterCondBuilder)
    }

    var dateRangeCondBuilder expression.ConditionBuilder
    if dateRangeCondition != nil {
        dateRangeCondition.ForEach(func(key string, value interface{}) {
            if dateRangeCondBuilder.IsSet() {
                dates, ok := value.([]interface{})
                if !ok || len(dates) != 2 {
                    fmt.Errorf("invalid date range condition: %v", value)
                }
                startDate := dates[0]
                endDate := dates[1]
                dateRangeCondBuilder = dateRangeCondBuilder.And(expression.Name(key).Between(expression.Value(startDate), expression.Value(endDate)))
            }
        })
        builder = builder.WithFilter(dateRangeCondBuilder)
    }

    expr, err := builder.Build()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("got error when building expression: %v", err)
    }

    params := &dynamodb.QueryInput{
        ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
        FilterExpression:          expr.Filter(),
        ProjectionExpression:      expr.Projection(),
        KeyConditionExpression:    expr.KeyCondition(),
        TableName:                 dbClient.TableName(),
        IndexName:                 indexName,
        ConsistentRead:            consistentRead,
    }

    result, err := dbClient.svc.Query(ctx, params)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("got error calling Query: %s", err)
    }

    err = attributevalue.UnmarshalListOfMaps(result.Items, items)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("got error unmarshalling: %s", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

how should i adapt my query function to take 2 parameter as startDate and endDate and build that condition